# Why is set_union = set_union.remove(i) giving error?

Tags: python, for-loop, set

So I was give the task to write a code to get the union of two sets.  And i wrote the the following 2 versions of codes.

**Version 1**

```
###### Set_Input ########

set_1 = input().split(" ")
set_2 = input().split(" ")

set_union = set_1 + set_2

###### Set_Union_Logic ########

for i in set_union:
     if set_union.count(i)>1:
          set_union.remove(i)
print(set_union)
```

**Version 2**

```
###### Set_Input ########
set_1 = input().split(" ")
set_2 = input().split(" ")

set_union = set_1 + set_2

###### Set_Union_Logic ########
for i in set_union:
     if set_union.count(i)>1:
         set_union= set_union.remove(i)

print(set_union)
```

Version 1 works fine but Version 2 gives me the following error

```
if set_union.count(i)>1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Can any one explain why writing ***set_union= set_union.remove(i)*** in the loop causes this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: because `list.remove` does not return anything. Also, version 1 has a bug because you are removing items from a list while iterating it

Comment: FWIW, you can just do `set_union = set(input().split()) | set(input().split())`

Comment: Also, you are not using a `set` anywhere, but with `list`.

Answer (score 2):

The `remove()` method of a list performs an in-place modification of the list and returns `None`. Since **Version 2** sets `set_union` to the return value, the next iteration tries to call a method of a `None` object, resulting in an error.

I should add that your `split()` is creating a list, so `set_union = set_1 + set_2` is adding two lists together and you may have duplicate values. If you actually want a proper set of unique values, you may want `set_union = set(set_1 + set_2)` instead.